# How can i extract the text which is not between Double quotes(" ")? in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a column which has some strings like these :-

1. `RM125 | RM250 | RMX250 | "RM 125" | "RM 250" |"RMX 250"`
2. `DR250 | DR350 | "DR 250" | "DR 350" | DR250S | DR250SE | DR350S | "DR250 S" | "DR250 SE" | "DR350 S"`
3. `RMZ250 | "RMZ 250" | "RM-Z 250" | "RMZ-250"`

now I want to extract only text which is not between double quotes(" ")

for example:

1. `RM125 | RM250 | RMX250`
2. `DR250 | DR350 | DR250S | DR250SE | DR350S`

Comment: Can't you do anything with the formula `=IF(IFERROR(FIND("""",A1),0)=0,A1;"")`? It will copy the `A1` (or other) cell content only if it hasn't any quotes.

Comment: It is unclear if this `RM125 | RM250 | RMX250 | "RM 125" | "RM 250" |"RMX 250"` in one cell or multiple cells. Please clarify. Also please include your attpemt to solve the issue. • If it is in one cell [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) and [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) could be very helpful tools. Give it a try on your own first.

Comment: Why have you not included RMX250 ? it is not in double quotes in the first instance that it appears. Or do you have the example incorrect or is it don't include duplicates?

Comment: @SolarMike sorry i forgot to mention RMX250. yes i want that also

Comment: @Pᴇʜ it is in one cell

Comment: @Pspl ITS NOT WORKING

Comment: Just an FYI, all caps is usually perceived as yelling on the internet, which isn't something you'd want to do to someone trying to help you for free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Thanks to @PEH for pointing out that my regex would not exclude quoted substrings if they were in the first location (and therefore not preceded by the `|`).  We have to make a special case for an initial quoted substring by changing:

```
.Pattern = "^""[^""]+""\s*\||\|\s*""[^""]+""\s*"
```

and I have done so in the code below.

You can use Regular Expressions implemented in VBA:

```
Function delQuotedStrings(S As String) As String
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "^""[^""]+""\s*\||\|\s*""[^""]+""\s*" ' changed from "\|\s*""[^""]+""\s*"
        .Global = True
        delQuotedStrings = .Replace(S, "")
    End With
End Function
```

eg. Data in A1:

```
B1: =delQuotedStrings(A1)
```

**OR** one could use a non-Regex solution:

```
Option Explicit
Function delQuotedStrings(S As String) As String
    Dim v, w, col As Collection, i As Long
Set col = New Collection
For Each v In Split(S, "|")
    If Not Left(Trim(v), 1) = """" Then _
        col.Add v
Next v

ReDim w(1 To col.Count)
For i = 1 To col.Count
    w(i) = col(i)
Next i

delQuotedStrings = Join(w, "|")

End Function
```

[image]

Explanation of the Regex:

### delete quoted substrings

```
\|\s*"[^"]+"\s*
```

- [Match the character “|” literally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Sic.png) `\|`
- [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
- [Match the character “"” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `"`
- [Match any character that is NOT a “"”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `[^"]+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match the character “"” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `"`
- [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: Nice work! But I would change the RegEx to something like `^"[^"]+"\s*\||\|\s*"[^"]+"\s*` just in case the first item begins alrady with `""` eg like in `"RM125" | RM250 | RMX250 | "RM 125" | "RM 250" |"RMX 250"` otherwise the first item will be ignored in your test, because it has no `|` in the beginning.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for pointing out the case that I had overlooked.  I've also added a non-Regex solution.